# Cannot Split string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Having some pretty basic issues trying to do this:

```js
var roleOptions = $('input#ctl00_plcContent_roles').val();
var options = roleOptions + '';
console.log(options);
var optionList = options.Split(',');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ctl00_plcContent_roles" value="abc,123">
```

The aim is to split this into an array and then add these options to a dropdown.

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: `Split` needs to be lowercase

Comment: Thanks Get Off my Lawn, can't believe something like that was making me bang my head against the wall!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `.Split()` to `.split()`

```js
var roleOptions = $('input#ctl00_plcContent_roles').val();
            var options = roleOptions + '';
            console.log(options);
            var optionList = options.split(',');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ctl00_plcContent_roles" value="abc,123">
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. This means that language keywords, variables, function names, and any other identifiers must always be typed with a consistent capitalization of letters.

So `Split` isn't valid while `split` is valid

```js
var roleOptions = $('input#ctl00_plcContent_roles').val();
            var options = roleOptions + '';
            console.log(options);
            var optionList = options.split(',');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ctl00_plcContent_roles" value="abc,123">
```

Comment: Thank you!  Classic stupid error by a newb